# Load light from configuration

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I've created a Light class which takes in three `Vector3fs` which are position, colour, and attenuation. I've been able to make a method that saves the Light to the config as so:

```
lightName: (0.0, 1000.0, -7000.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Now I need a method that can load and return the light with the saved information. So far I have:

```
public Light getLight(String name) {
    String line;
    try {
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith(name)) {
                line = line.replace(name + ": ", "");
                return new Light(new Vector3f(x , y, z), new Vector3f(r, g, b), new Vector3f(x1, y1, z1));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks!

----UPDATE------

Thanks to Johnny's response I was able to figure it out. Here is the fully working code:

```
public Light getLight(String name) {
    String line;
    float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, x1 = 1, y1 = 0, z1 = 0;
    try {
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith(name)) {
                line = line.replace(name + ": ", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
                parser.useDelimiter(", ");
                x = parser.nextFloat();
                y = parser.nextFloat();
                z = parser.nextFloat();

                r = parser.nextFloat();
                g = parser.nextFloat();
                b = parser.nextFloat();

                x1 = parser.nextFloat();
                y1 = parser.nextFloat();
                z1 = parser.nextFloat();
                parser.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        return new Light(new Vector3f(x , y, z), new Vector3f(r, g, b), new Vector3f(x1, y1, z1));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything in `line`, since all you need are the numbers. You do however need to parse the numbers from `line`.

You should parse the numbers either in a loop or all at once, assigning each number to a variable and then create the `Light`.

Something similar to the following should work:

```
public Light getLight(String name) {
    String line;
    double x, y, z, r, g, b, x1, y1, z1;

    try {
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith(name)) {
                Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
                x = parser.nextDouble();
                y = parser.nextDouble();
                // continue assigning variables

                // break out of while loop, only interested in one line
                break;
            }
        }

        return new Light(new Vector3f(x , y, z), new Vector3f(r, g, b), new Vector3f(x1, y1, z1));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @TotallyGamerJet I need to see your updated code, could you edit your question and add your updated code - **Note:** don't replace your old code, just add a new section to the end of your question with a header that says "Update" or something. If you replace your old code then the original question will be lost and my answer will lose its meaning.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to remove "(" & ")" and make the delimiter ", "